# Can you explain this partial derivative approximation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

How do they go from the left side to the approximation on the right? What does $j$ mean in this summation?
$$
{\partial f_i^n \over \partial t} \approx \sum_j {\partial f_i^n \over \partial \hat x_j} v_j^{n+1}
\\
\hat x_i = x_i + \Delta tv_i
$$
**Background:**

They are computing this value on a discrete grid. $f_i$ is a force on the grid at position $i$ (where $i$ is a vector in 3-dimensional space). $v$ is velocity and $x$ is position, both vectors. $n$ is the current time, and $n+1$ is $t + \Delta t$.

I may be able to provide further information, if something is unclear.
[Original source with equation here.](https://github.com/wyegelwel/snow/raw/master/docs/snow_implicit_math.pdf)

Comment: IMO this is just the application of the total differential
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_differential#Differentials_in_several_variables)
to the function $f=f(x_1,x_2, \dots, x_m)$ where the $x_i=x_i(t)$ are the time-dependent positions and $v_i = d x_i / dt.$ BTW: $i$ is **not** a vector in 3-d space it is the index for the coordinates. In the PDF there are $g$ vectors with three Cartesian coordinates, therefore
$j$ runs from $1\dots 3g$ (after suitable labeling of the $3g$ coordinates.)

Comment: I don't see why you'd sum over every grid node, just to get the force derivative at a single node. Do you just sum the 3 $j$'s that correspond with a particular node $g$?